# float vs. double strange behaviour in c

Tags: c, floating-point, double

i have troubles implementing a simple training program in C. The program should calculate a random cosinus or sinus of an angle, print the question "calculate cosinus/sinus of the angle x" to the user, who should type in the right answer in form "factor sqrt(value)". i.e. for cos(0) the user should type 1, for sin(45) the user should type `0.5sqrt(2)`. Most of the code is given in this task. The program doesn't work properly - for cos(270) the right answer is meant to be -0.000. Why is this happening? Why doesn't this code screams "division by 0"? Furthermore according to the task description the variable `right` should be of type `double` and `rueckgabe` of type `int`. But when i use double instead of float, i just get very high values (like 21234 or -435343). If i would use int as a return value of get_user_input(), the program won't work, right?

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PI          (acos(-1)) 
#define ACCURACY    1e-4    

float get_user_input(is_cos, angle){ 
    if (is_cos == 1) {
        printf("Berechnen Sie den Cosinus zu %i\n", angle);
    }
    else {
        printf("Berechnen Sie den Sinus zu %i\n", angle);   
    }
    float faktor, wurzel=1.;
    float rueckgabe;
    scanf("%fsqrt(%f)", &faktor, &wurzel);

    rueckgabe = faktor * sqrt(wurzel);

    return rueckgabe;

}

int main (){
    float right;
    int correct;
    int angles[] = { 0, 30, 45, 60, 90, 180, 270, 360 }; 
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    int is_cos = rand()%2; 
    int angle = angles[ rand()%(sizeof(angles)/sizeof(int)) ];

    if( is_cos == 1) {
        right = cos(angle/180.*PI); 
    }
    else {
        right = sin(angle/180.*PI); 
    }


    correct = fabs(get_user_input(is_cos, angle)/right - 1.) <= ACCURACY;

    printf("Ihre Antwort war %s!\n", correct ? "richtig" : "falsch");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first thing to do when debugging a problem is to look at the values, either in a debugger or with `printf()` statements.  Print out all the values that are material.  Check the selected `angle`; check the value of `angle/180.*PI`; check the value of PI.  Given your `scanf()`, you need to validate that `scanf()` returns 2; if it doesn't, you get garbage for `wurzel`.  Print the values of `faktor` and `wurzel`.  Always echo inputs so that you know that the computer sees what you think it should be seeing.

Comment: “Why doesn't this code screams "division by 0"?” Why should it? Dividing by zero is not an error in floating-point, it  just computes +inf, -inf or NaN.

Comment: “for cos(270) the right answer is meant to be -0.000” The non-null double-precision floating-point number `d` such that `cos(d) == -0.0` does not exist for a faithful `cos()`. Since floating-point numbers are more dense around zero, there always are enough doubles near `0.0` to represent how the argument was not exactly a multiple of π/2. It could have happened that one multiple of π/2 was so close to a double `d` that the cosine of `d` was zero, but it would have been one hell of a coincidence, which, it turns out, did not occur with the double-precision format as defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the sine and cosine return values in the range [-1, 1], I'd suggest that you use the absolute, rather than the relative, error. By replacing

```
correct = fabs(get_user_input(is_cos, angle)/right - 1.) <= ACCURACY;
```

with

```
correct = fabs(get_user_input(is_cos, angle) - right) <= ACCURACY;
```

everything should work as expected.

Generally I tend to use relative errors for large values and absolute errors for small values. You can combine both with

```
fabs(a-b)/(1.0+min(fabs(a), fabs(b)))
```

which (assuming you have a reasonable definition of `min`) tends to the relative error for large values and to the absolute error for small ones.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I replaced mine with yours and everything works well. Though this was also part of the task description and pre-defined code.

But I hope it will be accepted as well.

Comment: @user3598871: The decision as to whether absolute or relative error is the appropriate choice can be a difficult one to make. The combined error measure I described assumes (in a very hand-wavy way) that the inputs to the calculation whose result you are testing have absolute values somewhere near 1. For many real world calculations this is entirely appropriate (since we tend to pick our units so that this is true) but in the event that they are consistently much larger or smaller the results should be scaled down by typical magnitude of the inputs before comparison.

Answer (score 3):

In your program, both divisor and dividend can be close to / exactly 0 at the same time.

Your program does not give you a "division by zero"-error, because by default most floating point implementations silently give you infinity/NaN/0/-0, depending on the exact values you divide.

Answer (score 3):

The cosine to 270° is not exactly zero in floating-point arithmetic, because 270° cannot be expressed exactly in radians.

The following table shows the cosine of 270° (in the middle row) and in the first and last rows the cosines of the adjacent 32-bit floating-point numbers:

```
                         phi                        cos(phi)
                   4.7123885                -0.0000004649123
                    4.712389               0.000000011924881
                   4.7123895                0.00000048876205
```

And the same for 64-bit double-precision floating-point numbers:

```
                         phi                        cos(phi)
           4.712388980384689         -1.0718754395722282e-15
            4.71238898038469         -1.8369701987210297e-16
           4.712388980384691           7.044813998280222e-16
```

With the current floating-point precision, there's no way that `cos(phi)` with `phi` in the vicinity of 1.5*pi can be exactly zero.

You could fix that by writing a `cosdeg` that takes an argument in degrees and returns exact values for the angles where the cosines and sines are -1, 0 or 1 and values calulated with  radians otherwise. (Which then will happily generate the desired division by zero.)

Comment: AFAICT, it's a QoI issue whether `cos(phi)`, with `phi` nearly 1.5*pi will be exactly 0. So, no guarantees for non-zero either, even it it is unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to sin() and cos() are expressed in radians, not degrees.

Comment: The code already includes `angle/180.*PI` which should convert to radians.